# Routing Number for Yodlee DAG Account

Tags: yodlee

We have a Yodlee DAG catlog set up with a bank (and a few other institutions). They bank doesn't seem to have a routing number associated with it though. Is there a way to get/set one for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `<routingNumber>` tag under Bank `<bankAccount>` tag and for getting the Routing Number value for the DAG refer [here](https://developer.yodlee.com/Aggregation_API/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Sample_Data/Yodlee_Dummy_Account_Generator).

```
<routingNumber>111000614</routingNumber>
```